# Adding a Post Context to Home List View

Tags: django, django-views

I am going to be as descriptive as possible as I have a minor issue and I am stuck about how to fix it.
I am trying to add a Post to a list view, the Home list view has already an Item context.

In my project, a user can add a post and add an item each is a different app with different models.

So In my Home list view, I have my items looped and in each item, it is showing the user related to it.

What I am trying to do is check if this item.user has a post existing related to the user and if it does exist a button show appears in the page linking to another page with these posts.

In order words if there are Zero posts related to the user the button should not appear but if there is 1 or more the button should appear.

I have tried to add a condition to the template but it is not working correctly and I think there might be another easier way to do it through the views

Here is the post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

here is the template

```
<a href="{% url 'core:designer-posts' item.designer.username %}">
<button style="margin-top: 10px;text-transform: none;" button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">
Check all my products </button>
</a>
{% if posts %}
<a href="{% url 'score:user-posts' item.designer.username %}">
<button style="margin-top: 10px;text-transform: none;" button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">
Check my posts </button>
</a>
{% else %}
Show Nothing
{% endif %}
```

here is the item model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

With this code above it is showing the button although there are users with zero posts while it should only appear when a user has more than 0 posts

Here is the views

```
Here is the views

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 12
    template_name = "home.html"
    ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context['posts'] = Post
    return context
```

Comment: how do your checks work?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I am trying to figure out how to filter it out in the views if there are posts related to the user or not, this is the only way I am thinking of to check

Comment: Please share your views code as well

Comment: @ruddra I added the views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

annotate the queryset as

```
from .models import Item
from django.db.models import Case, When, BooleanField


class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 12
    template_name = "home.html"
    ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def get_queryset(self):
        has_post = Case(
            When(designer__post__isnull=False,
            default=False,
            output_field=BooleanField()
        )
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(has_post=has_post)
```

then in your template (`home.html`), now you can use **`.has_post`** attribute,

```
{% for item in object_list %}
    {{ item.title }}
    {% if item.has_post %}
        SHOW BUTTON
    {% else %}
        HIDE BUTTON
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note: You don't need to override the ***`get_context_data(...)`*** method, in this situation

Comment: I have a question if I want to add a filter to this code related to the posts, as I have a filter where they must first be approved so how can i apply this filter `queryset = Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)`

Comment: but this filter is related to the post model not the item model I got a field error and all the choices related to the item model attributes

Comment: oops... I didn't notice it.

Comment: The button should not appear if the post is `admin_approved=False`, the button should appear only if `admin_approved=True`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217057/discussion-between-ahmed-khairy-and-arakkal-abu).